# For a fixed surface area, what is optimal shape of a boat so that it can carry the most weight?

Tags: optimization, surfaces, solid-geometry

This problem is motivated by the [Penny Boat Challenge](https://littlebinsforlittlehands.com/penny-boat-challenge/): you are given an aluminum foil and you have to create a boat out of it that can hold the most amount of pennies.

I know that Archimedes' principle states that the upward buoyant force is equal to the weight of water displaced. This means that whatever shape is created, it should maximize the volume of water displaced for a fixed surface area.

Proven by the [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality), a sphere is the most optimal closed surface for that maximizes volume per surface area. However, the shape that we create from the aluminum foil doesn't necessarily have to be closed (a boat can have an open top). So my question is, what is the optimal shape in this scenario?

I have not been able to find any rigorous mathematical analysis or proof on this subject, which is surprising because I feel like the answer to this question could have a lot of applications. Anyone know any good resources (or even a solution possibly) for this problem? Is this an open problem in mathematics?

Comment: Seems like a good problem for Calculus of Variations techniques

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The question entails a lot more conditions than it might seem. In order to form a hull, aluminum foil must be folded or crinkled; that means a fixed area of foil does not yield a hull of the same area, but of smaller area. The hull must be water-tight and able to support a load, which leads to separate "area-reducing" constraints. Both are further constrained by thickness and material properties of the foil. That's not to say the question is bad, only that there is no short exact mathematical solution; it's arguably more engineering than math.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - while this question was inspired by the penny boat challenge, I think the question itself is "what shape having a planar face and a fixed surface area not including that face has maximal volume". It does not need to be formed from a flat sheet of aluminum foil.

Comment: There is a way to see the answer to this question experimentally, similar to the experiment that shows the full surface solution is a sphere: to reduce surface tension, soap bubbles minimize surface area for volume of air enclosed. A free-floating soap bubble is spherical (when not distorted by outside forces). Now consider a soap bubble floating on the surface of the liquid. It no longer has to maintain surface tension on the liquid boundary, only the air boundary. What shape does it form? A hemisphere.